# Lambdas and dynamic Menu updates?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, qt5

I am dynamically creating a menu in Qt5 using file names detected in a specific directory. I then proceed to use lambdas in order to connect those elements with an action such as

```
connect(test_action, &QAction::triggered, [=]()
            {fileSelected( filename );});
```

I am not sure what do do though in the case that I update that menu. These connections I presume won't close by themselves.

How would you suggest I tackle the issue of updating this menu at runtime?

Comment: What is your concern? Do you have any resource leak? What happens if you replace a lambda with a plain old function? Does the leak remain?

Comment: @n.m. What I am mainly interested in are general directions on how to update a dynamically generated menu, It would be easy if I had created the menu items myself but as I said they are created from a list inside a loop. In a few words I have no idea how to get rid of my previous menu items and create a new one based on the changes in the directory.

Comment: @Angew you never know man :)

Comment: So woud it be correct to say that lambdas and connections are not really relevant here?

Comment: No they very much are since I am using lambdas for connecting the actions for each menu element with the corresponding function. If I were to use QAction::setData() with signals and slots (in this case the connections would be automatically taken care of once the action was deleted from what I know) probably the solution would be different and you would want to know. In that sense I'm pretty sure the question is about lambdas an menus.

Comment: Back to square one. Do you have resource leaks with lambdas, yes or no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68946/discussion-between-dearn44-and-n-m).

Comment: How are you "updating" the menu exactly? If you delete the actions, then the connection is dropped as well. If you don't delete the actions, but "recycle" them, then you're creating new (multiple) connections for them every time you invoke `connect`.